# I need to convert data frame from character to integer

Tags: r, integer, dataframe, na

I replaced `NA`s with zeros in my data frame. This is my code

```
  na.zero <- function(x){
    x[is.na(x)]<-0
    return(x)
   }
   X=apply(MMD,2,na.zero)
```

Now I want to delete columns in my data frame that have more than 90% of zeros in the column. This is my code:

```
MMD=X[,-(which(apply(X,2,mean)<.1))]
```

I get an error because using the function changed all the values to characters.
How do I convert my data frame to integer values again?

Comment: can we have a reproducible example please?  These functions shouldn't have coerced numeric columns to character ...

Comment: You should be able to do `X = na.zero(MMD)` without even having to use `apply()`.  I imagine it was `apply()` that coerced all your data to character.